# Cropping images larger/longer than Page

Tags: microsoft-word

I routinely paste images into word that are longer than the page area, and for my purposes I need the images to fill the width of the Word doc; IOW I cannot get away with having a long skinny image where everything is too small to read.

When I crop, I see the top handles just fine, but the bottom cropping handles appear off the page. Typically I drag the top edge crop handle down until the lower handles are visible, then drag the bottom edge crop handle up to where I need it to be. Then move the top edge handle back up to its final position.

Certainly not an insurmountable task, but as much as I have to do this, it would be really nice to have this be more efficient, so my question is this...

Is there a setting or hotkey to cause the entire image and crop handles to be visible even if they overlap other pages? I've tried using the Crop >> Fit and Crop >> Fill but they don't seem to be doing what I need.

Any insight/help would be appreciate. I'm also an AutoHotKey user, so if someone knows of a way to leverage AHK I'm open to that as well. Thanks!

Comment: <rant>People use Word as 'one tool to rule them all' when in fact it's one of the poorest tools available for page layout. Find a better tool. </rant> [sorry]

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin for your thoughtful and helpful response, and especially for taking into consideration that I understand Word is not the ideal tool, but happens to be the one I currently have at my disposal.

Answer (score 0):

You can crop the picture numerically in the "Format > Picture..." dialog box:

[image]

Different versions of Word may vary, but in Word 2011, you get to this dialog either from the Format menu, or by CTRL-Clicking on the picture.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good call Bandersnatch! I'll look into this, I think it may work for me. Also looks like I may be able to automate this as well.

Comment: So, click on the green checkbox and/or the upvote triangle if you found this helpful.  I wouldn't say anything, but only 2 of my last dozen or so answers got any appreciation at all. <sob> :-D

Comment: I did, but apparently I'm too new/inactive on here to matter. When I click the upvote button I get this message:

"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Well, pfffffftttt.  But thanks anyway.  I'm glad to have helped.  That's supposed to be it's own reward anyway, right?  :-D